AWS Amplify resources not working in production environment - Amplify.configure() not being called prior to generateClient()
my team is building an application with Amplify and React. We are having issues with our GraphQL APIs working in our dev environment, as well as through Postman. However when called in our production environment, we are getting "The API configuration is missing. This is likely due to Amplify.configure() not being called prior to generateClient(). This is extremely similar to this issue that we found:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12986
We have ensured that we are properly importing our configuration file and that is exists when passed into Amplify.configure. We are also using Cognito for authentication and that piece works fine, so we are not sure what is the problem. Any advice would bve greatly appreciated, thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you using Amplify Gen2? using mono repo? How are you generating config? what you are passing to Amplify.configure()? Where have you placed Amplify.configure() code? Please be more precise.
